# How do I stop Eclipse from moving my line comments after annotations?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I am setting some annotations on a class, and comments on the same line as the annotations, such as:

```
@SampleAnnotation // sample comment
@AnotherAnnotation // another comment
public class SampleClass { }
```

However, every time I format the file, my same-line comment ends up being moved to the **next line**. Not only is this undesirable because it moves my comment, but even worse it puts the comment in a confusing place. The above sample becomes:

```
@SampleAnnotation
// sample comment
@AnotherAnnotation
// another comment
public class SampleClass { }
```

How do I stop Eclipse from moving these comments after formatting? Or, how do I get Eclipse to move the comments to the line above, rather than the line below? Thank you.

Comment: Don't write comments in the first place. Focus instead, on making the name of the method/annotation name more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution thus far is to signal Eclipse to turn off the formatter for such blocks. That is, the original code would become:

```
// @formatter:off
@SampleAnnotation // sample comment
@AnotherAnnotation // another comment
// @formatter:on
public class SampleClass { }
```

Ensure you have the off/on tags enabled in Eclipse:

1. In the main menu, access `Windows` → `Preferences`.
2. On the **left**-hand side, access `Java` → `Code Style` → `Formatter`.
3. On the **right**-hand side, click <kbd>Edit</kbd>.
   [image: Java → Code Style → Formatter → Edit]
4. In the **dialog** that appears, click the **right-most tab**, `Off/On Tags`.
5. Ensure that `Enable Off/On tags` is **checked**.
   [image: Off/On Tags → Enable Off/On tags]

   - If you're using a built-in profile, you'll have to change the name at the top of the dialog in the `Profile name` field.
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>. When the dialog closes, click <kbd>OK</kbd> again to finish applying the settings.